# SQL: How to divide text from a row in different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If anyone can give me a hint how to get data from a row with text in different columns. I will have an example below.
Much appreciated

I have a column called TEXT that contains:

```
TEXT
<FROM> USER_SCHEMA1.T_POSTAL_CODES
<FROM> USER_SCHEMA2.T_USER_NAMES
<FROM> USER_SCHEMA3.T_LOCATIONS
```

Desired result: TWO DIFFERENT COLUMNS

```
SCHEMA_NAME     TABLE_NAME
USER_SCHEMA1    T_POSTAL_CODES
USER_SCHEMA2    T_USER_NAMES
USER_SCHEMA3    T_LOCATIONS
```

How to translate this into sql?

This is what i need from ALL_SOURCE, but column TEXT to put it in two columns one SCHEMA_NAME and one TABLE_NAME.

```
select * from ALL_SOURCE S
where S.OWNER_NAME like 'FINANCE_SCHEMA%' -- in order to be on the right schema
and S.TEXT like  '<FROM%'; -- what to use next?
```

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `substring()` and `stuff()` with `charindex()` to find the location of the first period and/or space in the string.

```
select 
    schema_name = substring([text]
        , charindex(' ',[text])+1
        , charindex('.',[text])-(charindex(' ',[text])+1)
      )
  , table_name  = stuff([text],1,charindex('.',[text]),'')
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/EEMU6399

returns:

```
+--------------+----------------+
| schema_name  |   table_name   |
+--------------+----------------+
| USER_SCHEMA1 | T_POSTAL_CODES |
| USER_SCHEMA2 | T_USER_NAMES   |
| USER_SCHEMA3 | T_LOCATIONS    |
+--------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage PARSENAME for this pretty easily. I would really recommend you stop using reserved words as column names. It makes code a lot more challenging than it needs to be.

```
with MyTextTable as
(
    select MyText = '<FROM> USER_SCHEMA1.T_POSTAL_CODES' union all
    select '<FROM> USER_SCHEMA2.T_USER_NAMES' union all
    select '<FROM> USER_SCHEMA3.T_LOCATIONS'
)

select *
    , [SCHEMA_NAME] = parsename(REPLACE(MyText, '<FROM> ', ''), 2)
    , TABLE_NAME = parsename(REPLACE(MyText, '<FROM> ', ''), 1)
from MyTextTable
```